# jQuery setting class to a variable

Tags: jquery, class, variables

I am trying to set class to a variable. My code is:

```
var vtxt = $(this).attr("id");
$("('" + vtxt + "')").addClass("on");
```

It does not work this way. I've tried several things with no luck. What is the right format for adding a setting class to a variable?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this:

```
var vtxt = $(this).attr('id');
$("#"+vtxt).addClass('on');
```

But, it's worth noting that (given the above example) you can just do this and get the same result:

```
$(this).addClass('on');
```

Comment: $("#"+vtxt).addClass('on');
This does it.

Thanx a lot!